# Is there a workaround to be able to drag and drop input types with Firefox and HTML 5?

Tags: firefox, html, drag-and-drop

I have a cross browser solution for dragging and dropping using HTML 5 that works for all elements in IE 9, Chrome, and Safari.  Firefox works for everything except input types such as textboxes.

I have done a lot of research on this with a lot of help from these resources:

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/
http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

I have also scoured the HTML 5 spec and the Firefox MDN and other resources and have found no solution to the problem. I would hate to fall back to a jQuery library, but it just looks like HTML 5 is not ready for prime time and that I may have to do so.

Has anyone tried this and have a solution or am I going too far over the edge here?  Glad to see workarounds are so prevalent in HTML 5 already and my dream of HTML 5 being cross browser so quickly destroyed with the first new thing I try.  The spec makes it sound simple.  Add a draggable attribute and handle a few events.  Except, IE only supports anchor tags and image tags.  Webkit browsers need CSS and Firefox apparently doesn't support input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dragable` attribute for firefox and `-webkit-user-drag` css property for webkit-based browsers.
See http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html#link9